# onSubmit() is not working in React.js

Tags: reactjs, forms

I have a `form` like below

```
<form className="ui form" onSubmit={this.update}>
     <input type="text" defaultValue={this.props.element} onChange={this.handleChange1}/>
     <input type="button" value="Update" className="ui positive icon button"/>
 </form>
```

My update function is like below

```
update = event => {
   console.log('hello');
   event.preventDefault();  
}
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The submit button should not be of type `button`, but type `submit`.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  update = event => {
    console.log("hello");
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form className="ui form" onSubmit={this.update}>
        <input
          type="text"
          defaultValue={this.props.element}
          onChange={this.handleChange1}
        />
        <input
          type="submit"
          value="Update"
          className="ui positive icon button"
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

your button should be `type='submit'`